# SQL statement left join where children is null or

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have two tables 'user_rights' as parent table and 'assigned_rights' as child. I need to show all rights which has no child in table 'assigned_rights' and if there is a child I have to check if one of the child's is not equel to a user_id.

```
   SELECT   ur.right_id, 
      ur.right_name, 
      ur.right_description, 
      ur.right_level, 
      ura.user_id
   from user_rights  as ur
   left join assigned_rights as ura
   on ur.right_id = ura.right_id
   where ura.user_id is null or ura.user_id <> 'abc'
```

My select works fine when there are no childs and also if there is a child and userid match field 'user_id'. Problem is, if there are childs with different user id's.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the child related use inner join

```
 SELECT   ur.right_id, 
      ur.right_name, 
      ur.right_description, 
      ur.right_level, 
      ura.user_id
   from user_rights  as ur
   inner join join assigned_rights as ura
   on ur.right_id = ura.right_id
   where ura.user_id <> 'abc'
```

Comment: No, I need the Parents which has no child or if there are child's non of the childs has the value 'abc' in user_id.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT   ur.right_id, 
      ur.right_name, 
      ur.right_description, 
      ur.right_level, 
      ura.user_id
   from user_rights  as ur
   left join assigned_rights as ura
   on ur.right_id = ura.right_id and ura.user_id = 'abc'`

Comment: Thks, I tryed, but then the result include also the childs.

Comment: Can you give example in your tables and example of result?

Comment: SELECT ur.right_id, 
ur.right_name, 
ur.right_description, 
ur.right_level, 
ura.user_id
from user_rights  as ur
left join assigned_rights as ura on ur.right_id = ura.right_id
where ura.user_id is null 
union all
SELECT ur.right_id, 
ur.right_name, 
ur.right_description, 
ur.right_level, 
ura.user_id
from user_rights  as ur
inner join assigned_rights as ura
on ur.right_id = ura.right_id and ura.user_id <> 'abc'

Comment: Solved the challenge SELECT
 ur.right_id, 
 ur.right_name, 
 ur.right_description, 
 ur.right_level, 
 ura.user_id
from user_rights  as ur
left join  assigned_rights as ura
on (ura.right_id = ur.right_id and ura.user_id = 'abc')
   
where ura.user_id is null